# Lumen: InvalidArgumentException for model timestamps with $dateFormat = 'U'

Tags: laravel, lumen

> There are around 15 different question on stack overflow which looks similar to this but are not.

I'm using lumen 5.6.*(latest at the time) In the model I've declared:

`protected $dateFormat = 'U';`

The Exception occurs when converting model to JSON using:

`$model->toJson()`

Error trace:

```
(1/1) InvalidArgumentException
Trailing data
in Carbon.php line 909
at Carbon::createFromFormat('U', '2018-09-02 18:04:51')
in HasAttributes.php line 748
at Model->asDateTime('2018-09-02 18:04:51')
in HasAttributes.php line 129
```

Also, as per the mutator documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators I've have declared:

```
protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    /* 'deleted_at'*/
];
```

Comment: Where's `2018-09-02 18:04:51` come from because that clearly isn't a `U` format..

Comment: Please, provide de code where you store the attribute.

Comment: The timestamps are for type timestamp in my database and I had inserted the timestamp values through phpmyadmin by assigning current timesatmp. Do I need to change the type of columns to int?